# Xamarin forms how to keep label text value after navigation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On my Main Page, I will set my label text (#lblStartDateTime) to current time stamp when user click on a button. It will navigate to Second Page, and once I click "done" button, it will go back to Main Page.

When I navigate back to Main Page from Second Page, my label text disappeared. Does anyone know how to keep the label text value after navigation?

**Main Page**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test
{
   [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public string previouspagevalue;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        lblEndDT.Text = previouspagevalue;
    }
    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());


        string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;


       }

   }
}
```

Second Page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test
{
   [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SecondPage: ContentPage
{

    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void btnDone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage mainpage = new MainPage();
        string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblEndDateTime.Text = edt;
        mainpage.previouspagevalue = lblEndDateTime.Text;
        Navigation.PushAsync(mainpage);

       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share us some code about this problem? Codes about lblStartDateTime in your mainPage.

Comment: Hi I updated my codes already! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `btnDone_Clicked` event , you should use `Navigation.PopAsync` to go back to MainPage, `Navigation.PushAsync(mainpage);` means to go to a new MainPage not the previous Page.

```
  protected void btnDone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

           Navigation.PopAsync();

     }
```

Please read [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) to learn about how NavigationPage works.

**Update**, you can pass the value you need to the `SecondPage` when you push to `SecondPage`:

Codes in `MainPage`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string previouspagevalue;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        previouspagevalue = "I'm previouspagevalue";
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        //if you set the lblEndDT.Text = "someValue"; in the secondPage, there is no need to update it here
        lblEndDT.Text = previouspagevalue;
    }

    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Pass the parametere you need when you go to SecondPage 
        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT));

        string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;

    }
}
```

SecondPage:

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    Label MainPagelblEndDT;
    MainPage mainPage;
    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SecondPage(MainPage mainP,Label lblEndDT)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Get the lblEndDT reference here
        MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
        //Get the MainPage reference here
        mainPage = mainP;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //Use it
        MainPagelblEndDT.Text = edt;      

        mainPage.previouspagevalue = MainPagelblEndDT.Text;

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Pass-Value-BetweenPages) and you can check it. Feel free to ask me any question if you have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. I changed PushAsync to PopAsync but my end date time disappeared after navigating back to main page :(

Comment: @Charis wait a second, I will show you how to do it.

Comment: @Charis You want to change the text of `lblEndDateTime` in the second page and then go back to MainPage, right?

Comment: Sorry, just another question.. How do I keep the starting time from the first click? Meaning if the user navigates back and forth with Main Page and Second Page, the start time should be the time stamp when it was first clicked

Comment: Then you should not call `lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;` everyTime in method btnOffline_Clicked. Add a bool value there to make sure if it is your first click then decide whether to update the text of lblStartDT  or not.

Comment: Okay thank you! I managed to get it work.. I wish I can chat you but I can't.. sorry for the trouble again, I would like to ask how do you change image source? I am using image button with a grey background (to indicate disabled), so once they click done, I would like to change my image button to another image (blue to indicate enabled). Do I use the same method to call the image button in my other pages?

Comment: You can set the source again when you want to set a new image.

Comment: I tried to set the image source on my second page but they say Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you wrap your pages in a navigation stack, use a `NavigationPage` and navigate to next page then when you pop back it will maintain your state.

In your `App.xaml.cs`

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourFirstPage);
```

Then push a page into the navigation and when you want to go back just do a

```
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Goodluck

Feel free to get back if you have queries